# Socket.io failing to connect because of nsp

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a problem with socket.io@^1.0. The setup is fine because it works locally, the server is correctly configured and when i try to connect to the server from my Angular APP it works fine with this:

```
io.connect("localhost:8080");
```

The connection is established and i can send and receive event. Now in the production environment, "locahost:8080" is replaced with the address of the server Launched:

```
io.connect("https://domain-name.com/api");
```

I know that the problem here is the `/api`, since socket.io is considering it as a namespace and it's trying to connect to it, in my network console I see 500 Internal server error with the address `https://domain-name.com` without the `/api` when i replace the request url to add the `/api` I get a 200 OK with type octet-stream.

So the question here is: how do I connect to the correct path without consideration of the namespace?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: So what is causing that 500 error?

Comment: 500 error is caused by the nginx server because Angular is trying to access https://domain-name.com/socket.io/EIO.... instead of  https://domain-name.com/api/socket.io ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the `path` option (documented [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client#socket)):

```
// client
var socket = io.connect('https://domain-name.com/', {
  path : '/api/socket.io'
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much men :)